# How to SUM LARGE 5 largest elements out of 8 numbers in a row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

In Excel I am able to get the output using this formula:

```
=SUM(LARGE(C5:L5,{1,2,3,4,5}))
```

But in Google Sheets I am unable to get the right answer. Can anyone please help?

In the image below, observed 7th row the sum must be 49/50 using the technique `=SUM(LARGE(C7:L7,{1,2,3,4,5}))` but the solution is showing as “10” instead of “49”.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an array instead

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(LARGE(C7:L7,{1,2,3,4,5})))
```

[image: Google sheets SUM LARGE multiple nth largest elements]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`LARGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094008)

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Is there an easy way of converting this to a range of rows?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I guess you wanted to use this for your [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67384835)? It would involve cumulative sum but never tried it out. I tend to avoid overcomplicated formulas, unless **really** needed.

Comment: yeah was just trying to expand on the premise. I try to avoid complicated formulae if I can too, I’m not as formula savvy as I could so oftentimes I find a custom function does the job just as well even if sometimes a bit slower. Will take a look at cumulative sim though, thank you for the response.